# Serialize DataTable (Dataset) to Object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datatable, dataset

I have one class and one query from the database, filling DataTable in the DataSet. I would like to populate the object with the data from the DataTable & DataSet. How can I do so?

Object:

```
 public class Marks
    {
        public List<Mark> MarkList { get; set; }

        public Marks()
        {
            MarkList = new List<Mark>();
        }
    }


    public class Mark
    { 
        public String Number { get; set; }

        public String Word { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateIn { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateOut { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried to do so:

```
private void BindMarksSerialize()
{      
    FillDataTable(dtMarks, MarksCMD);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    dtMarks.WriteXml(stream);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Marks), new XmlRootAttribute("Marks")); 
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Out.xml", stream.ToArray());


    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Out.xml");
    var marks = (Marks)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();
}

private void FillDataTable(DataTable dataTable, Object sqlCommandContainer)
{
    var sqlCommand = sqlCommandContainer as SqlCommand;
    var sqlDataAdapter = sqlCommandContainer as SqlDataAdapter;
    if (sqlDataAdapter == null && sqlCommand == null)
        return;

        dataTable.Clear();
        if (sqlCommand != null)
        {
            sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
            dataTable.Load(sqlCommand.ExecuteReader());
        }
        else
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
 }
```

The result is needed to populate XML:

```
<Marks xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MarkList>
    <Mark>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Word>123123123</Word>
      <DateIn xsi:nil="true" />
      <DateOut xsi:nil="true" />      
    </Mark>
  </MarkList>
</Marks>
```

I got:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Mark>
    <Number>110938</Number>
    <Word>110938</Word>
    <DateIn>1993-04-08T00:00:00+05:00</DateIn>
    <DateOut>2002-02-04T00:00:00+04:00</DateOut>    
  </Mark>
</NewDataSet>
```

Prompt can anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understant your problem correctly, You are having trouble with writing a DataSet to an XML file but have no trouble writing a list of mark class type object to XML.

You can use reflection to make a reusable function which will read a Datarow from any Datatable and assigns it to any object you pass as parameter. if you want List of that object then you can iterate through DataRows of DataTable. In sample below I am generating an object from a single row. (This is kind of reusable mapping.)

```
public static object ConvertDataRowToObject(object Object, DataTable DataTable)
{
    try
    {
        if (DataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow DataRow = DataTable.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
            if (DataRow != null)
            {
                Type ObjectType = Object.GetType();
                //Get public properties
                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] _propertyInfo =
                     ObjectType.GetProperties();
                foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo _property in _propertyInfo)
                {
                    _property.SetValue(Object, (DataRow[_property.Name.ToString()] is System.DBNull ? null : DataRow[_property.Name.ToString()]), null);
                }
                return Object;
            }
            else return null;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch (Exception excp)
    {
        Common.WriteErrorLog(excp.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now When I need to call this static reusable function, I can do it like this sample.

```
Database _dbFactory = Common.Database;
                DataSet dset = new DataSet();
                Object[] _dbObject = DataBaseHelper.CreateConnection();
                dset = _dbFactory.ExecuteDataSet("Jwl_sp_SearchByProductCategoryById", new object[] { _Id });
                DataBaseHelper.CloseConnection((SqlConnection)_dbObject[0]);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = dset.Tables[0];
                var objectTobeConverted = new DataLogic.Database.Jwl_ByProductCategory();
                ConvertDataRowToObject(objectTobeConverted, dt);
```

I serialized this object using Javascript serializer. Next Step in your case is to write to an xml document for which You can use xmlSerialization, or I will suggest using XMLWriter.

```
public static string GetJSONSerializedObject(object myItem)
{
    try
    {
        if (myItem != null)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _propList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            Type myObjectType = myItem.GetType();
            //Get public properties
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] _propertyInfo =
                 myObjectType.GetProperties();
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo _property in _propertyInfo)
            {
                string _key = String.Empty;
                string _value = String.Empty;
                _key = _property.Name.ToString();
                _value = (_property.GetValue(myItem, null) != null) ? Convert.ToString(_property.GetValue(myItem, null)) : "";
                _propList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(_key, _value));
            }
            if (_propList.Count > 0)
            {// Serializing an object's properties
               System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer;
                jsSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                System.Text.StringBuilder _strBuild = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                jsSerializer.Serialize(_propList, _strBuild);
                return _strBuild.ToString();


            }
            else { return null; }
        }
        else { return null; }
    }
    catch (Exception excp)
    {
        Common.WriteErrorLog(excp.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is having trouble writing the CORRECT xml.  Notice the last two paragraphs.  One is "this is what i want", the other is "this is what i get"